# $_GET without variable name

Tags: php

Many times I tried to write different types of codes in different languages. When I tried to write something like this:

```
if (!isset($_GET[""])) $_GET[""] = false;
```

The compiler does not report an error. OK, we have this construction **without variable name**. Is here one way to use this construction in practice? I think it's nonsense.

I think that only **$_GET** is usable in practice, like:

```
if (count($_GET) > 0) do something
```

Comment: Uhmm. I shouldn't set the $_GET. This is for urls like `http://google.com?myget=helloWorld` So now I have `$_GET['myget'] = 'helloWorld';`

Comment: Why should it report an error? What is the question? Why is this being upvoted?

Comment: some friends might have upvoted

Comment: In theory, `""` is an empty string, not like `null`, so `$array[""]=true` is syntax-valid. And I think you _can_ make use of it if you like (though tempering `$_GET`/`$_POST` is a little out of expected).

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the usability of $_GET[""] - you can't set it using URL.

If you go to the URL `test.php?=3` you will get an empty `$_GET`

If you go to the URL `test.php?""=3` you will be able to access it using `$_GET["\"\""]`

So there is no way to set a variable in the URL and retrieve it with `$_GET[""];`

You can set the key to an empty string from the code however:

```
$_GET[""] = 3;
echo $_GET['']; // 3
echo $_GET[""]; // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`empty($_GET)` and `count($_GET)` are working here for me!

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you want to achieve by this code:

```
if (!isset($_GET[""])) $_GET[""] = false;
```

It's possible for php to assign empty string as array key and it will be accessible like:

```
$array[0]['']
```

For your checking you can use such function for example:

```
function GET($key, $default = null) {
    return isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : $default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you test the following code with a url like 'http://domain.com':

```
print_r($_GET);
echo '<br>';
if(isset($_GET))
{
   echo '$_GET IS SET<br>';
}

if(!empty($_GET))
{
   echo '$_GET IS NOT EMPTY<br>';
}

if(count($_GET) > 0)
{
   echo '$_GET IS NOT EMPTY<br>';
}
```

you 'll get

```
Array ( ) 
$_GET IS SET
```

According to that then is up to you what you want to check or do
keep in mind that $_GET is always set
even if you do http://www.domain.com or this http://www.domain.com/index.php?test=adsf

What you did with $_GET[''] = 'smthing' is like having an array arr['test'] = 'smthing'; altho you didn't gave a key of test instead an empty one, which you can't handle properly when it comes to $_GET.

so you should check for smthing specific if you ask me.

```
if(isset($_GET['test']) && $_GET['test'] == 'adsf')
{
   doSomething();
}
```

This is just a simple example further validation should occur.